# How to Generate Random Number of Barcode in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I need a code generator in jQuery that when clicking on the button it appears in the input text a number of 13 digits, start in number 7.

This is the code in my view:

```
<div class="form-group <?php echo !empty(form_error('barcode')) ? 'has-error':'';?>">
    <label for="barcode">Barcode:</label>
    <div class="input-group barcode">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <button class="fa fa-barcode" title="Generate Random Barcode"></button>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode" name="barcode" required value="<?php echo set_value('barcode');?>">
    </div>
    <?php echo form_error("barcode","<span class='help-block'>","</span>");?>
 </div>
```

This is the input text + button:

[image]

The generated number like this:

[image]

Comment: You'll use Javascript for this. JQuery is just what you use to make the page change. Try starting by just making a random number generator, then implementing the barcode stuff later.

Comment: I don't understand, you're showing us the generated number which means that you know how to implement this

Comment: I only need genera a number of 13 digits, and show this in the input text

Comment: I removed the duplicate because I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1349426/754119) would be more useful. It seem like you don't need 13 digits, but 12 because the first number is always 7. You can define the possible combination to be only digits by changing `possible` in that answer and also change `i < 5` to `i < 11` to get a random 12 digits combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```js
$(document).on('click', '#barcode_btn', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var val1 = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 999999);
   var val2 = Math.floor(10000 + Math.random() * 99999);
   $('[name="barcode"]').val('7 '+val1+' '+val2);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="barcode" value="">
    <button id="barcode_btn">Generate Barcode</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not _perfect_ because you can't create numbers beginning with zero using the suggested solution

Comment: Now how can I compare the values that already exist in my product database?

Comment: Yes, But @WilsonicX's requirement was just to generate a random number

Comment: This does not generate a random number?

Comment: @WilsonicX, you can do that with an ajax call to a server page, where you'll check whether the input value exists in the database or not.

Comment: @WilsonicX yes it does

Comment: This solution WILL generate random numbers, but you won't get numbers that begins with zero such as `044355` (That number was taken from the screenshot in the question)